# how to fix a lawn mower that leaks gas

Tags: lawn-mower, gasoline

My father-in-law handed down a fairly new Craftsman lawn vacuum that has a 6.75 Briggs and Stratton engine. When we put gas in it, it leaked all over the place.

We took off the air filter and the gas is coming out of the carburetor.

Comment: Assuming that you've checked for loose or leaking fuel lines, the float valve may be stuck, or maybe there's a bit of dirt in the needle valve. Fixing it is probably [not a very difficult repair](http://valveproducts.net/needle-valve/how-to-clean-the-needle-valve-on-carburetor) if you're familiar with small engines, otherwise a small engine repair shop can take care of it.

Comment: My last mower had a hole corroded through the bowl, but the reason for that leak was pretty obvious.  If it's coming out of the top of the carb, then +1 for "stuck float".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused a small rubber seal, which they call the seat. Briggs & Stratton Carburetor Needle and Seat picture:

[image]

The needle and seat are sold as a package for about $5.  You have to take the carburetor apart to install it.